# Camera errors when running Python script at boot from rc.local

Tags: raspbian, python, picamera, mmal

I have a Python file that calls the camera to take video when a motion sensor is triggered. 
I am running it at startup using rc.local (I have the '&' at the end).
When I run it normally, it works fine, just not when I run it at boot.
I am getting this error:
    picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed it. I hope this helps someone...
I had used `~/path/to/file.py` as the directory to which I wanted to store the footage taken by my Python code.
I replaced this with absolute reference: `/home/pi/path/to/file.py` and that solved it.

Comment: Given that you have answered your own question you are allowed to accept it as the answer (after a delay which I suspect has now elapsed!) - it is likely that it is the system (possible the `root` user) that is running the `/etc/rc.local` - although the new-fangled `systemd` might change things nowadays - which is NOT the user that would have `/home/pi` as the home directory which `~` as a initial path component would use (instead it would try to use `/root/path/to/file.py`).